# Azure WebJobs QueueTrigger attempts (and fails) to convert message's byte[] body to string

Tags: binding, parameter-passing, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a storage queue to which I post messages constructed using the `CloudQueueMessage(byte[])` constructor. I then tried to process the messages in a webjob function with the following signature:

```csharp
public static void ConsolidateDomainAuditItem([QueueTrigger("foo")] CloudQueueMessage msg)
```

I get a consistent failure with exception

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Program.ConsolidateDomainAuditItem ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'msg' ---> System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [FF] at index -1 from specified code page to Unicode.
 at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
 at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
 at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes)
 at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetCharCount(Byte* bytes, Int32 count, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
 at System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength, Encoding encoding)
 at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage.get_AsString()
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage.Queue.StorageQueueMessage.get_AsString()
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Triggers.UserTypeArgumentBindingProvider.UserTypeArgumentBinding.BindAsync(IStorageQueueMessage value, ValueBindingContext context)
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Triggers.QueueTriggerBinding.<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Looking at the code of `UserTypeArgumentBindingProvider.BindAsync`, it clearly expects to be passed a message whose body is a JSON object. And the `UserType...` of the name also implies that it expects to bind a POCO.

Yet the MSDN article [How to use Azure queue storage with the WebJobs SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/) clearly states that

> You can use QueueTrigger with the following types:
>
> - `string`
> - A POCO type serialized as JSON
> - `byte[]`
> - `CloudQueueMessage`

So why is it not binding to my message?

Answer (score 0):

The WebJobs SDK parameter binding relies heavily on magic parameter names. Although `[QueueTrigger(...)] string` seems to permit any parameter name (and the MSDN article includes as examples `logMessage`, `inputText`, `queueMessage`, `blobName`), `[QueueTrigger(...)] CloudQueueMessage` requires that the parameter be named `message`. Changing the name of the parameter from `msg` to `message` fixes the binding.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any documentation which states this explicitly.

Comment: The name of the parameter doesn't factor into the binding logic at all - you can name it whatever you want. Perhaps some other change occurred that made your function start working? It can't be the parameter name :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

public static void ConsolidateDomainAuditItem([QueueTrigger("foo")] byte[] message)

CloudQueueMessage is a wrapper, usually the bindings get rid of the wrapper and allow you to deal with the content instead.